# Are mysqli_result::free and mysqli_stmt::free_result the same?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote this code :

```
$stmt = $link->prepare($statement_string);

// [...]

$result_m = $stmt->result_metadata();
if ($result_m) {
  $stmt->store_result();

  // [...]

  $stmt->free_result();
  $result_m->free();
}
```

Is that code right ?

I read the doc [mysqli-stmt.result-metadata](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php) and [mysqli-result.free doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php).  I also read this post : [...free-mysql-result-after-storing-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114972/do-ive-to-free-mysql-result-after-storing-it) but I didn't find my answer.

EDIT :

What I want to know is : will the `$stmt->free_result();` just liberate some memory allocation done by `$stmt->store_result();` or clearly free the memory of the `mysqli_result` object built by `$stmt->result_metadata();` ?

Comment: I guess you should have read "[mysqli-stmt.free-result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php)" instead. +1 for reading the docs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to these pages:

[mysqli-free-result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)

[mysqli-stmt-free-result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php)

meta data and actual statement data (rows) are different objects so you must clear them both separately.

exactly as you did in your code.